# AS3: Trigger artificial MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, dispatchevent

I am converting a simple flash 'drumset' application to support TUIO multitouch using the tuio as3 reference implementation from http://www.tuio.org/?flash

As a quick and dirty solution, i am trying to trigger an artificial MouseEvent, but nothing seems to happen :( where is my error? is this even possible? thanks already!

here's the code:

```
package {

    import org.tuio.tuio.*;
    import org.tuio.osc.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.ui.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.media.*;

    public class drumsets2 extends MovieClip implements ITuioListener {

        private var tuio:TuioClient;

        var soundS01:Sound = new S01();
        // more sounds...

        public function drumsets2(){
            this.tuio = new TuioClient(new LCConnector());
            this.tuio.addListener(this);

            drum1.hitS01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playS01);
            // more event listeners for sounds...
        }


        // this is where the 'magic' is supposed to happen

        public function addTuioCursor(tuioCursor:TuioCursor):void {
            stage.dispatchEvent(
                new MouseEvent( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, true, false, tuioCursor.x*stage.stageWidth, tuioCursor.y*stage.stageHeight )
            );
        }


        function playS01(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var scS01:SoundChannel = soundS01.play();
        }

        // more play functions...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event listener is not on the stage, it is on drum1.hitS01, which I will assume is a DisplayObject as it is not defined anywhere in your attached code. All you should need to do is dispatch the event on that object, not on the stage:

```
drum1.hitS01.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, true, false, tuioCursor.x * stage.stageWidth, tuioCursor.y * stage.stageHeight));
```

Comment: +1. Though the code for localX and localY doesn't make any sense. I know you just pasted that part from the OP sample, but I though it was worth noting this. Maybe using `drum1.hitS01.mouseX` and `drum1.hitS01.mouseY` makes more sense; or just leaving the default, as there was really no click, so x and y coordinates don't have any real meaning here.

Comment: thanks! but what i am trying to do is simply forwarding the touch events to the whole stage, so i won't have to check whether the touch event was inside a hihat, basedrum or so... is there a way to accomplish this behavior?

Comment: Then you need an event listener on the stage if you want to forward the event to it. Also, good call Juan, I figured it had some significance for him so I just left it alone.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, it seems like you're just trying to call the playS01 function from code? If so you can, anywhere in your class, call `playS01(null)`.
You need to pass it null if it's not coming from a mouse event so it doesn't bug you about not receiving an expected argument.

Comment: the thing is that there are _lots_ of perfectly functioning mouse events and i don't want to mess with all that code. i thought it would perhaps be possible to just artificially trigger the existing events. i need to do this in other projects as well, so this would be a cool solution that i could use for all of them...